# Why does Anglian OE "-tene" have unetymological "e" on the end?

Tags: old-english

Why does Anglian Old English "-tēne" (Proto-Germanic *tehun) have unetymological "e" on the end?
Why does English "ten" have no long "ee"?

Comment: not just Anglian. West Saxon has -tīene, so the final e appears to be more general in Old English

Comment: Speculation, but perhaps it's an adopted plural ending (i-stems or pronominal masculine as with strong adjectives).